# Сравнить файлы по количеству строк в них

Tags: python, строки, файлы, txt

Нужно создать функцию, которая будет запрашивать у пользователя путь к каталогу. В этом каталоге она должна найти **все txt файлы**, сравнить их по количеству строк и объеденить **в один файл**. При этом файлы должны записываться в **порядке возрастания числа строк**, файл с наименьшим количеством строк должен идти первым, в котором больше всего - последним. Файлов в папке может быть **произвольное** количество.

**Структура** должна быть следующая: 1) Имя файла; 2) Количество строк в нем; 3) Текст файла ----> следующий файл по такой же схеме.

На данный момент получилось это:

```
from os import path


def file_txt_files():
directory = input('Укажите путь к каталогу: ')

if path.exists(directory):
    pattern = '*.txt'
    glob_path = os.path.join(directory, pattern)
    list_files = glob.glob(glob_path)
    new_file = 'new_file.all'
    if list_files:
        for file_name in list_files:
            with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as fr, open(new_file, 'a', encoding='UTF-8') as fw:
                fw.write(f'\n\n------------ {file_name}\n\n')
                for line in fr:
                    fw.write(line)
```

Запутался в порядке действий, что лучше сделать сначала? Возможно лучше будет сначала открывать каждый файл, считать количество строк в нем, потом сравнивать с ....(чем-то) и записывать в итоговый файл?

```
line = 0
for line in open('*.txt', 'r'):
    line += 1
```

Типа такого. Подскажите как лучше и лаконичнее сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здась используется **компаратор**. Линейный порядок на множестве документов при сортировке задается их длинной.

```
import os
import glob
from os import path

def comparator(doc):
    return len(doc)

def write_with_sort(direct):
    if path.exists(direct):
        files = []
        pattern = '*.txt'
        glob_path = os.path.join(direct, pattern)
        list_files = glob.glob(glob_path)
        for file in list_files:
            with open(file) as f:
                files.append(f.readlines())
        files.sort(key=comparator)
        # for file in files:
        #     file[-1] += '\n'
        print(files)
        with open('all.txt', 'w') as f:
            for file in files:
                f.writelines(file)
                f.write('\n')

write_with_sort(input())
```